# Eclipse Crashing on Launch JVM terminated. Exit code=2 Error

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, jvm

I wanted to Start Java Programming on Eclipse.. I ran into this problem when trying to run Eclipse, having installed latest Version..
I tried Googling The issue but didnt Found out answers For the same.

Problem:

```
Eclipse Craches with the Following Error
 JVM terminated.Exit Code=2
 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.quinox.launcher_1.3.0v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.quinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1a54_58
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.exlipse.quinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Can someone please guide me how to solve this specific problem?I Had To Start With My Java Programming But This Error has Halted me  ....
Please Help...

Comment: Post whole error not just exit code.

Comment: What's your java version, 6,7 or 8? 32bit or 64bit? What is your system param 32bit or 64 bit, Win 7 or win 8 or even some earlier?

Comment: jdk 1.8.0_25 and win8 64bit ..

Comment: you didn't change anything in eclipse.ini?

Comment: no i didnt change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall Java; Delete all version of java on your machine. 
Download the latest version and install it.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Path under environment variable is referring to incorrect version of java, do check whole path properly, sometimes "javapath" term is also mentioned under referring to incorrect version of java sdk.
So simply remove that incorrect reference and It would work fine.